# NPM shows a 403 when installing public packages

Tags: javascript, npm

When I am trying to install my deps with NPM it gaves me à 403 status code. I am installing them using docker. Everything was going well till this morning when npm wasn't able to install dependencies anymore. The problem is only on my server. Locally the deps can be installed, no problems. I do not have any proxy on my server.

When I issue this command directly in my server :

```
wget https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

I get :

```
> wget https://registry.npmjs.org/
--2020-05-29 12:09:35--  https://registry.npmjs.org/
Resolving registry.npmjs.org (registry.npmjs.org)... 2606:4700::6810:1b23, 2606:4700::6810:1523, 2606:4700::6810:1423, ...
Connecting to registry.npmjs.org (registry.npmjs.org)|2606:4700::6810:1b23|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2020-05-29 12:09:35 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

I really do not understand what can be wrong in my server? Again, it was working yesterday, nothing changed in the server...

My server is an OVH Kimsufi.

Comment: can you put a sudo before wget

Comment: or you can add user-agent to wget.     
wget --user-agent="Mozila" https://registry.npmjs.org/

Comment: seems to be an OVH problem : https://twitter.com/ovh_status/status/1266310329631465472

Answer (score 2):

Ok, seems to be an OVH problem : https://twitter.com/ovh_status/status/1266310329631465472